# Liferay portlet development with Eclipse and plugins SDK

Tags: java, jsp, portlet, liferay

I am trying to create some simple portlet, which has some jsp Pages communicating with the java backend and vice versa. But any documentation states different procedures, filenames and functions, than those used in the basic portlet, created by the Liferay plugins SDK. Does anybody know an 'SDK compliant howTo' regarding this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170597/how-to-solve-error-of-jsp-page/16206991#16206991

Answer (score 1):

Your portlet should be jsr168 compliant, independent from Liferay.

You should try [Spring Portlet MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/portlet.html), and study the sample portlet application that comes with the Spring distribution.