# how to solve error of jsp page?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, liferay

I have string type method in **java** file it contain string array and when I try to call in **jsp**, it give me an error.

```
public String[] ordering(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse)  
    throws IOException,PortletException
```

JSP:

```
<% 
  TestiPortlet obj=new TestiPortlet();
  String str[]=obj.ordering(actionRequest,actionResponse);
  out.println(str[0]);
%>
```

Error:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:- actionResponse cannot be resolved to a     variabl-actionRequest cannot be resolved to a variable

    Stacktrace:
    javax.portlet.PortletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /html/testi/list.jsp at line 8

    5: 
    6: <% 
    7:   TestiPortlet obj=new TestiPortlet();
    8:   String str[]=obj.ordering(actionRequest,actionResponse);
    9:   out.println(str[0]);
    10: %>
    11:
```

Comment: This is a very interesting way of calling a method with parameter `ActionRequest` and `ActionResponse`. I would be really interested to know what is this wonderful usecase you are trying to achieve here :-). And can you please paste the whole stack-trace, like which line this error is coming. Thanks

Comment: @RasabihariKumar show above edtion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error says it all, your jsp is not finding `actionRequest` and `actionResponse` object.

These objects need to be included in the JSP by having this code at the top of your JSP:

```jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>

<portlet:defineObjects />
```

And as @RasabihariKumar correctly mentions, this is not the way how a `Portlet` class should be used. For testing or learning, this may be fine but for real projects I don't think this is a good practice to do because these are expensive objects and it simply does not seem right to use a Portlet as a Utility class to process data like this, it breaks the principle of [cohesion](http://www.ehow.com/info_8717133_cohesion-software-engineering.html).

Portlet classes should be used to send request (by using `renderURL` or `actionURL` or `resourceURL`) to and get the response just like we do for servlets.

#### Edit after his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170597/how-to-solve-error-of-jsp-page/16183736?noredirect=1#comment23135838_16183736):

You can go through the [liferay](/questions/tagged/liferay) wiki to get useful links to learning resources, I would recommend the developer guide and the books `Liferay in Action` and `Portlet in Action` for the best way to develop portlets in liferay.

For now, the simplest way is to write code in `doView` method of your portlet which would be called when your portlet JSP page is rendered, just retrieve the list from the database in your `doView` and put in as a request attribute:

```jsp
renderRequest.setAttribute("listAttr", listFromDatabase)
```

and then use this `listAttr` in the JSP as:

```jsp
String[] str = (String[]) renderRequest.getAttribute("listAttr");
```

Going through source code of [sample portlets](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/portlets) developed by liferay might also help.

Comment: then tell me what i should do... i have portlet class  i try to fetch record from database to portlet class using resultset. now i want to show my all data to web browser. i cant write my this logic in jsp file .. thats why i use portlet class for business logic and jsp file for display purpose. please guide me .. how to do this